# How to retrieve all data from a subcollection of all document

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Flutter for my app. I want to retrieve all document (not only for one user) of a subcollection and display in the app. Each user has a subcollection of Baggage and a subcollection of Car.

This is how I store in Firebase:

```dart
String createAt = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
var ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Trips').doc('userId').collection('Baggage').doc(createAt);
FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {transaction.set(ref, {
    'departure': city1.text, 
    'destination': city2.text, 
    'weight': _weightcontroller.text, 
    'id': userId, 
    'departureDate': date.text, 
    'username': firstname, 
    "timestamp": createAt,
  }); 
});
    
    
var ref1 = FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('Trips')
  .doc('userId')
  .collection('Cars')
  .doc(createAt);
```

How to retrieve data from subcollection 'Baggage' for all users. If there is best way so structure these data and retrieve easily, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore has something called collectionGroup query where you can get all subcollections if they have same collection name. Which can be done as

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('Baggage').get();
```

This will give you all the documents across all rooms. For reference [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query)

Comment: A collectionGroup query can help you get all collections and subcollections from Firestore, as long as all have the same name.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have tried several things without success. This is what i get when using stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance  .collectionGroup('Baggage').orderBy('timestamp', descending: true).snapshots(),                                                                  
   [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query( collectionGroup=Baggage order by -timestamp, -__name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}. Please can you tell me how to set rule for collectionGroup?         Thank you.

Comment: @Vincent you can read this documentation about setting up a rules on your Baggage Collection. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure

Comment: Thank you, I managed to make it work. The only problem is that I have to remove order by timestamp, so it is not in order. But this is not serious.  Thank you a lot.